# Can I route traffic of VPC-2 via VPC-1's VPN using VPC peering?

Tags: amazon-vpc

VPC-1 has a VPN connection which allows access to IP's within the internal corporate range.

Can I create a new VPC-2 and route all traffic that's destined for the corporate range through VPC-1 that already has the access?

I was thinking VPC peering and Route Tables could help me do this.

I've set up the corporate CIDR to route via the VPC peering between VPC1-VPC2, but so far no traffic is arriving when I type telnet corporate-IP 22 and I've created the routes.

[image]

10.16.0.0 - AWS EC2 peering works fine
10.182.0.0 - Range that works in 10.16.0.0/16 and gets routed via a VPN in that range.

[image]

The 10.16.0.0/16 range has perfect access to 10.182.0.0/26, but I'm trying to give 172.21.0.0/16 access to there too, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What routes did you create in the VPCs?

Comment: I've placed a picture of my route tables.